# Win 7/8/10 Security Log: Allow non-admin to read (but not change) the Security log

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, permissions, event-log

I'm trying to give a non-Administrator account the ability to only read (not change) the Security log.  The overall goal is creating small system, running with reduced privileges, that responds to different security events.  The system needs to run as the logged-in non-admin user so it can interact with their desktop to display various messages (and yes, I know that there are commercial solutions that already do that).

Unsuccessfully tried:

- Giving the user "read" permissions on the following registry entries:

.

```
KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Security
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Security\Security
KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\*
```

I tried explicit permissions as well inherited from the parent object.

- Changing the permissions for C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Security.evtx

In all cases, I verified the effective permissions, and restarted the computer to ensure the winevent services etc. are aware of the permission changes.  Any ideas?

Comment: [Giving Non Administrators permission to read Event Logs Windows 2003 and Windows 2008](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/janelewis/2010/04/30/giving-non-administrators-permission-to-read-event-logs-windows-2003-and-windows-2008/) may help you.